# In R, how to plot bars only in a certain interval of data?

Tags: r, plot

My problem is very simple. 
I have to plot a data series in R, using bars. Data are contained in a vector `vet`.

I've used `barplot`, that plots my data from the first to the last:
`barplot(vet)`, and everything was fine.

Now, on the contrary, I would like to plot not all my data, but just a part of them: from 10% to the end.
How could I do this with barplot()?
How could I do this with plot()?

Thanx

Answer (score 4):

You need to subset your data before plotting:

```
##Work out the 10% quantile and subset
v = vet[vet > quantile(vet, 0.1)]
```

Comment: Thanks csgillespie. Another short question: now no value is shown on the x axis, and I don't know why. Is there a command to say "show increasing numbers from min to max on the axis"?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Ask another question, but give example data that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear exactly what you want to do.

If you want to plot only a subset of the bars (but the whole bars) then you could just subset the data before passing it to `barplot`.

If you want to plot all the bars, but only that part beyond 10% (not include 0) then you can do this by setting the `ylim` argument.  But it is very discouraged to do a barplot that does not include 0.  You may be better off using a dotplot instead of a barplot if 0 is not meaningful.

If you want the regular plot, but want to exclude plotting outside of a given window within the plot then the `clip` function may be what you want.

The `gap.barplot` function from the `plotrix` package may also be what you want.

Comment: Couldn't decide whether csgillespie's answer was better because of economy or your answer was better because of breadth.